# is it possible to have logic filter in this sql?

Tags: sql

If this is possible. I would like to select the order # one time.
according to these trn codes 'CSS', 'CQU', 'CWA', 'OCS', 'CRF',
    'BCS', 'CCN', 'RBC', '001', 'RQU', 'RRF', 'RWA

currently there can be a row for each order and multiple trn code
so we can have
order#    ottrnc
12345     001
12345     RBC
12345     CWA

would it be possible to only select one order#? but the catch is, all orders get 001 first. then if something is done with the orders it gets other trn codes. in the case above we would want either the RBC or CWA row.

```
SELECT T01.OTTRT,T01.OTCOM#, T02.OHPTTC, T02.OHSLR#, T01.OTORD#,      
T01.OTTRND, T02.OHORDT, T02.OHORDD, T02.OHTTN$, T01.OTUSRN,           
T02.OHOSTC, T01.OTTRNC FROM ASTDTA.OETRANOT T01 INNER JOIN            
asTDTA.OEORHDOH T02 ON T01.OTCOM# = T02.OHCOM# AND T01.OTORD# =       
T02.OHORD# WHERE T01.OTTRNC IN ('CSS', 'CQU', 'CWA', 'OCS', 'CRF',    
'BCS', 'CCN', 'RBC', '001', 'RQU', 'RRF', 'RWA') AND T02.OHORDD >=    
20140101 AND T02.OHOSTC <> 'CN'
```

Comment: Have you looked at using SELECT DISTINCT in your query to pull out unique values?

Comment: Yes it's possible, but how do you determine the correct `trn` to return?  You're going to need to use an aggregate query most likely for this.  Also, which `RDBMS` are you using?

Comment: in order to help, you will have to tell us how you determine the correct trn code to select.  in the above case you listed, which would be returned and why?  RCB or CWA?

Answer (score 1):

As Mat Richardson notes, `SELECT DISTINCT` might meet your expectations in terms of "select order # one time".  Without knowing how the rest of your columns are populated/filled, this query below should work in most DBMSs and should give you back one order number for every order that has an OTTRNC of 001 And also at least one of any of the other codes you enumerated.

```
   SELECT DISTINCT 
    T01.OTTRNC
    FROM ASTDTA.OETRANOT T01
    WHERE T01.OTTRNC IN ('CSS', 'CQU', 'CWA', 'OCS', 'CRF',    
    'BCS', 'CCN', 'RBC', '001', 'RQU', 'RRF', 'RWA')
    AND  
       EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM ASTDTA.OETRANOT IT01
        WHERE IT01.OTTRNC = ('001')
        AND IT01.OTORD# = T01.OTORD#
        )
```